# Python 3.3.3 Running Files with Command Line

Tags: python

I just started learning Python 3.3.3 with the book "Learning Python" from O'Reilly by Mark Lutz, 4th Ed.

I was able to run code interactively, but when I tried to run the code from files through the command line, I just kept getting syntax errors.

FYI, I am using Windows 7.

The book asks that one create a file using a text editor with the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.platform)
print(2 ** 100)
x = 'Spam!'
print(x * 8)
```

I did this using notepad and saved the file with the suffix "py" and the file type "all.files" so there would not be a "txt" file saved.  When I try to run the script in the python command I get an error message.  I've tried entering the PATH but that as not worked either.  It is located in C:\Python33\

Any guidance you are able to provide is very welcomed.  I've tried numerous ways for the past 1 hour.

Comment: "I get an error message" is not very descriptive. What is the error?

Comment: first off, I'd recommend getting the [5th edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do) which was published in June. It's fully updated for Python 3.3 (as well as discussions about 2.7 where appropriate), so any script errors may have been fixed there. That being said, your code as posted is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks MattDMo. I was thinking the same thing, that perhaps an updated version of the book.  More than I can afford at the moment.

Comment: stanac  I saved it as script1.py

Comment: I tried to run it using "python script1.py" as indicated in the book.  When that didn't work I tried "C:\Python33\python script1.py"

Comment: tried many variation on that theme too.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have the following in my `Path` variable,

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

Is that what you have? Maybe close your command line and open it again, or shut your machine off and turn it on again--the system variables do not update instantly.

Comment: I tried   C:\Python33;C:\Python33\script1.py and still got back "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: I closed it the command line and opened it again.  I will try shutting off my machine and rebooting now.  Thx

Comment: Hi cjohnson318.  I tried shutting down and still get the syntax error

Comment: Geez, that beats me, then. Your syntax looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

where have you saved your script?

what is the output of this?

```
cd C:\Python33; dir; python script1.py
```

Comment: I got back this:   File "<stdin>", line 1 (then next line) cd C(with a ^ under it ):Python33; dir; python script1.py then next line

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Saved script in C:\Python33\script1.py

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the file you saved as ".py" has the right ext instead ".txt", otherwise you can easly download "notepad ++" to save as the right extension".
If the file you saved is right, then you have to execute the "cmd.exe", and go to the "python33" folder using "cd c:\Python33" or where you have it, Once you're in the right directory, write "python PATH.py", where the PATH is the right path of the file.py, or you can just move the file into the cmd.

Hope it helps